# Looking to finish my url encoding in php

Tags: php, parameters, urlencode, symbols, slug

I have a slug function that I am using from another tutorial.

```
 public function createSlug($slug) {
        // Remove anything but letters, numbers, spaces, hypens
        // Remove spaces and duplicate dypens
        // Trim the left and right, removing any left over hypens
        
        $lettersNumbersSpacesHypens = '/[^\-\s\pN\pL]+/u';
        $spacesDuplicateHypens = '/[\-\s]+/';

        $slug = preg_replace($lettersNumbersSpacesHypens, '', mb_strtolower($slug, 'UTF-8'));   
        $slug = preg_replace($spacesDuplicateHypens, '-', $slug);
        $slug = trim($slug, '-');
        
        return $slug;
    }
```

It works great. I have two questions.

1. It gives me 'amp' instead of removing the '&' symbol. Not sure if it should be like that.

   For eg.

**original url**

```
http://www.mywebsite.com?category_id=1&category_name=hot & dogs
```

**new url using slug function**

```
http://www.mywebsite.com?category_id=1&category_name=hot-amp-dogs
```

and second, how do I decode it back to the original form so that I can echo it out on the page? It doesn't look right echoing with dashes.

Comment: simple -amp- as you see it in the link eg.

Comment: for decode use two fields in your db for slug and original url so any need of original fetch from db. so no need to decode

Comment: I understand. I suppose i'll have to look up on how to do that.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "htmlspecialchars_decode". see below modified function:

```
function createSlug($slug) {
// Remove anything but letters, numbers, spaces, hypens
// Remove spaces and duplicate dypens
// Trim the left and right, removing any left over hypens
$slug   =   htmlspecialchars_decode($slug);

$lettersNumbersSpacesHypens = '/[^\-\s\pN\pL]+/u';
$spacesDuplicateHypens = '/[\-\s]+/';

$slug = preg_replace($lettersNumbersSpacesHypens, '', mb_strtolower($slug, 'UTF-8'));   
$slug = preg_replace($spacesDuplicateHypens, '-', $slug);
$slug = trim($slug, '-');

return $slug;
}
```

For decode, agree with [Rakesh Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/878888/rakesh-sharma). Use database to manage this.